# webrtc getUserMedia : how to get a stream from getUserMedia and publish it to SRS?

Tags: simple-realtime-server

How to get a stream using html5 getUserMedia and publish that to SRS ?

I want to get a stream directly from browser and not using OBS or ffmpeg.

Any sample available ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it dpends on your use scenario.

If you want to do live streaming, please see [this post](https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v5/doc/getting-started#webrtc-for-live-streaming), the media flow:

```
Browser --WebRTC--> SRS --HLS/HTTP-FLV--> Viewer
```

If you want to do video meeting, please see [this post](https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/docs/v5/doc/webrtc#sfu-one-to-one), the media flow:

```
Browser <--WebRTC--> SRS <--WebRTC--> Viewer
```

Note that for video meeting, there should be NxN streams in a room.

Comment: How to send Browser's video stream from webcam to SRS?

( Browser --WebRTC --> SRS --HLS/HTTP-FLV--> Viewer )

Above document mentioned only ( SRS --HLS/HTTP-FLV--> Viewer ) using ffmpeg.

How to implement ( Browser --WebRTC --> SRS )?

Furthermore if client want to share his screen( not webcam ) to viewers via SRS, how to do it?

Comment: (Browser --WebRTC--> SRS --HLS/HTTP-FLV--> Viewer)
  would you like to provide detailed source code for above step?
Furthermore I need rtc_publisher.html, too.
Thanks.

Comment: All code is open source, please see [srs_publisher.html](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/blob/develop/trunk/research/players/rtc_publisher.html). Please contact us by discord if need more discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Solution.
Check the below Code...

HTML CODE: Here you need only Video tag.

Index.html

```
    <video id="remoteScreen"  autoplay="true"></video>
```

Screenshare.js file

```
    const getLocalScreenCaptureStream = async () => {try {
    const constraints = { video: { cursor: 'always' }, audio: false };
    const screenCaptureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(constraints); return screenCaptureStream; } catch (error) {
    console.error('failed to get local screen', error)}}
```

main.js

```
    var localStreamScreen = null;
    async function shareScreen() {localStreamScreen = await getLocalScreenCaptureStream(); console.log("localStreamScreen: ", localStreamScreen)}
```

screenshare.js

```
    function handleRemoteStreamAddedScreen(event) {
    console.log('Remote stream added.');
    alert('Remote stream added.');
     if ('srcObject' in remoteScreen) {
    remoteScreen.srcObject = event.streams[0];
     } else {
    // deprecated
    remoteScreen.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
    }
     remoteScreenStream = event.stream};
```

Hope, it will work for you.